# "Illness" during etikaf in Ramadan

Tags: ramadan, sick

What if someone become ill during etikaf. And for medication he/she have to visit the doctor. Can any person visit the doctor during "Etikaf".

Comment: Etikaf doesn't mean that one must stay 100% of the time in the mosque. In fact one must leave the mosque to perform some human needs. But to what level these needs might be relaxed needs to be clarified.